# JavaScript selected value in dropdown box

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have created function for creating a div, when you select the value in dropdown box, based upon the length the number of divs will be created, so the code is:

```
<select onchange="test()" id="selected_opt">
                <option value="0" selected>-Select-</option>
                <option value="1">Communication</option> 
                <option value="2">XXXXXXXXXXXXX</option> 
                            </select>
```

The function test is:

```
function test(){
var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
if(result == 1){
    
    var i = 0,
    c = model_details_json.communication,
    j    = c.length,
    communications_div = document.getElementById("model_communication");

    if(j == 0){
        alert('nothing');
    }

    for (; i<j; i++){
        var communication = c[i];
        var create_div = document.createElement('div');
        create_div.id = 'communication_id'+i;
        create_div.name = 'communication';
        var create_anchor = document.createElement('a');
        create_anchor.innerHTML = communication.communication_name;
        communications_div.appendChild(create_div);
        document.getElementById(create_div.id).appendChild(create_anchor);
        create_anchor.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
 create_anchor.setAttribute("onclick","sample('"+communication.communication_name+"','"+create_div.name+"')");
            }
        }
```

For example, the length is 6 means the six number of divs will be created, so what the problem is when I again click on communication in select dropdown i.e. already the six divs have been created, when do it again then again six divs are created, so totally 12 divs created when you do it again it goes for 6 multiples.

So what I need is the number of div would not be repeated, and it should be validate whether the user is clicking the same value in dropdown.

Comment: for say length is 3 , When clicking on first time, 3 divs will be created or appended, then when i do it again another 3 divs are creating so totally 6

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/03/26/how-to-dynamically-removedelete-elements-via-javascript/) to remove `div` elements considering your parent div `model_communication`.

You need to implement logic by checking if the div exist and stop the loop when you get a message like 'Div is already removed' as shown in the example.

In order to do so create div elements along with id

```
var newdiv = document.createElement('div'); 
newdiv.setAttribute('id', id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove all divs before create the new ones. Try adding a class name to it:

```
var create_div = document.createElement('div');
create_div.className = 'communication_div';
...
```

Now you can select the divs. Before the for statement add these lines to remove the divs with 'communication_div' class name:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('communication_div');
for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) { 
    divs[i].parentNode.removeChild(divs[i]);
}
```

Every script run will generate new divs and remove old ones.

Answer (score 0):

use js map object to put selected value or length as key into the map then everytime user clicks a value, first check for its existence in the map. If not found in the map, that would mean length is not repeating and divs will be created.

something like:

```
var selectedValues = new Array();
.......
var result = get_id.options[get_id.selectedIndex].value;
if(selectedValues["val_"+result]) {
     return;
}
selectedValues["val_"+result] = true;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can check if the div is already created or present on page using getElementById('elementId') before creating it.

like in you code

```
for (; i<j; i++){
  if(! document.getElementById('communication_id'+i)){ // do if element is not present on page
    var communication = c[i];
    var create_div = document.createElement('div');
    create_div.id = 'communication_id'+i;
    create_div.name = 'communication';
    var create_anchor = document.createElement('a');
    create_anchor.innerHTML = communication.communication_name;
    communications_div.appendChild(create_div);
    document.getElementById(create_div.id).appendChild(create_anchor);
    create_anchor.setAttribute("href", "javascript:void(0);");
    create_anchor.setAttribute("onclick",
          "sample('"+communication.communication_name+"','"+create_div.name+"')");
     }
}
```

Comment: This would fail to match requirment in case if user has 6 divs and wants 4 in next iteration

Comment: In this case you should clarify your question, you need to remove all created divs before adding new. There are 3 approach of doing it
1) Clear communications_div's innerHtml
2) assign a common name to all divs those you created, and get those usng document.getElementsByName, iterate through each and remove it.
3) Use some JS framework like jQuery to make your life easy, apply some common class on all divs and remove those by identifying those with given class before creating new.

Answer (score -1):

Use `replaceChild()` instead of `appendChild()` on the Element object.

Comment: This would fail to match requirment in case if user has 6 divs and wants 4 in next iteration